# Ao executar uma Activity quero que a execução aguarde o encerramento para continuar, ou execute sequencialmente o código

Tags: android, android-activity

Como faço para executar uma activity e depois de fecha-la continuar a execução do código de onde parou, exemplo:

```
    listmarcacoes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapter, View viw, int posicao,long id) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(posicao);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EdicaoMarcacao.class);
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            String resposta = cursor.getString(1).toString();
            if(CalculoHora.isHojeData(resposta)){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Use a aba RESGISTRO para marcações do dia!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                params.putString("diafiltro", resposta);
                intent.putExtras(params);
                //  Aqui quero que a execução aguarde a activity ser executada!
                startActivity(intent);
                //  Aqui a execução continua apos o encerramento da actitity!
                // Executanto posteriormente o metodo lista()
                lista();
            }
        }            
    });
```

Preciso que seja desta forma pois quando chamo a activity "EdicaoMarcao" ela altera os valores de listview , desta forma quando fecho a segunda tela quero que atualize a primeira.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Você pode usar:**

```
listmarcacoes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapter, View viw, int posicao,long id) {
        cursor.moveToPosition(posicao);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EdicaoMarcacao.class);
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        String resposta = cursor.getString(1).toString();
        if(CalculoHora.isHojeData(resposta)){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Use a aba RESGISTRO para marcações do dia!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            params.putString("diafiltro", resposta);
            intent.putExtras(params);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 9);//9 é o requestCode número inteiro para a identificação
        }
    }            
});
```

**Depois sobrescrever o método**:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 9 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Bundle params = data.getExtras();
        String resposta = params.getString("diafiltro");
        lista();
    }
}
```

**Na activity EdicaiMarcao faça:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle params = getIntent().getExtras();
    String resposta = params.getString("diafiltro");
}
```

**Depois faça as alterações que desejar e quando terminar de executar a activity EdicaiMarcao.class faça:(obs:na EdicaiMarcao.class)**

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("diafiltro", resposta);
intent.putExtras(params);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Só confirmando, o código "onActivityResult" coloco na Activity atual, certo?, já o código para quando terminar coloco na EdicaiMarcao.class, correto?, mas qual método EdicaiMarcao.class posso colocar?

Comment: Isso correto.Você pega o bundle passado pela atual activity e faz alteracões na EdicaiMarcao.class e depois passa a sua resposta pelo bundle, e em seguida você finaliza essa activity.. depois no método onActivityResult você pega a reposta que está no bundle e depois chama o método lista() para atualizar os valores de sua listView.

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado!